# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I normally never ask stuff here but I just can't for the life of me, figure out why this piece of code isn't working. I've went through countless websites and youtube videos and that same snippet seems to be working for them. Most grateful if anyone could steer me in the right direction.

P.S, GetPosts is a component that I will be displaying on the Index Page of my nextJs project.
I know that if I remove the whole posts.map() thingy and replace by a simple helloWorld text, it displays well in the browser... so the issue should be with the whatever i'm trying to map.
I've also tried using another link for the api  (one from FakeJson api) and still same issue.

[Image: ***The Error***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acNqo.jpg)

```
export default function GetPosts({posts}){
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => {
                <div key={post.id}>
                    title: {post.title}
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getPosts");
    const data = await response.json();
    return {
        props: {
            posts: data,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're passing through `posts` into your `GetPosts` component? Sounds like whatever is driving that prop is initially undefined (even though you might set populate it later) so you're getting this error

Comment: use `props.posts.map` instead of `posts.map`, since it is nested

Comment: The console output in your linked images shows an HTTP 500 Error. Is this error related to the `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getPosts")` call? If yes, `posts` is not set, because the call failed ...

Comment: UPDATE:
Thank you for your answers.

i figured out what was wrong. So it seems that getServerSideProps does not working in components; therefore, my GetPosts component was not receiving the props, causing the "undefined" issue

Comment: Feel free to add the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where the error is:

After this line: const data = await response.json();
Do console.log(data) to see if any data is there.

On this line: {posts.map((post) => {
put a question mark after posts. So if there's no data, it doesnt do anything.

{posts?.map((post) => {

This is how I deal with .map issues.